# What could a good file storage solution would be using Glassfish and Neo4J?

Tags: java, glassfish, neo4j

I'm currently developping a JavaEE application using glassfish, and I would like to save some files on server (for sharing them between multiple clients).

As of today, that application stores all its data into a Neo4J DB. But, I have read some articles that could suggest that Neo4J may not (due to its lack of horizontal scalability) be the best solution to store files. So, how could I store those files on my server ?

Comment: Do refer distributed FS like Gluster or binary storage of Mongo

Comment: Would really like to know **why** that question got downvoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store files in a convenient fashion, I deployed the very useful [sourceforge WebDAV servlet](https://github.com/ceefour/webdav-servlet) (far better, in fact, than Glassfish/Catalina one) and stored those files in my domain databases dir.